# Persist backstack info of fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I am using **Fragments** in my app project. All the fragments are add to backstack.

```
...
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
...
```

In my application, I would like to persist the information of back stack in order resume to the previously viewed fragment once the app is crashed.

What is the correct way to persist the **back stack** information for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, why would your app crash :p Is this a feature?

Second, I feel you will have to do this yourself. You will need to maintain an ID or TAG relating to the currently displayed Fragment, and save this into the SharedPreferences. When the application next loads, you check to see if there is an ID/TAG present, and load a fragment based on this.